# (iOS 8)Can I use Real Game Center Account to test an iOS app?

Tags: ios8, game-center

I`m integrating game center into my project. Now is using sandbox account to login. But I want to send my application to other tester. Those tester dint try to plug their devices to macbook before, so cannot enable the sandbox option. So I want to make my app can login by using Real Game Center account. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You must use a sandbox account until it is approved by apple. It is very simple to create sandbox accounts with iTunes Connect though. Just go to your Users and Roles -> Sandbox Testers -> Plus button. Simply create a sandbox account with a working email that is not associated with an apple ID yet, and you can make your testers sandbox accounts.